# Combine multiple polygon layers in one interactive map with tmap

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to draw one single interactive map in R using the tmap package.

I have one polygon shape with data from various years. When I use `tm_shape() + tm_fill()` for each year it automatically makes a new, separate map for each year.

I would like to plot multiple layers in one interactive map. This way, by selecting different layers in the drop down menu on the left, you can see the change over the years.

Does anybody know if this is possible and how to do this?

This is my script:

```
require(rgdal)
require(tidyverse)
require(tmap)
require(tmaptools)

# files
download.file("https://www.haarlem.nl/bestandsopslag/bestanden/Opendata/Veiligheid_-_Misdrijven.csv", "veiligheid_misdrijven_haarlem.csv")
download.file("https://www.cbs.nl/-/media/_pdf/2016/35/shape%202014%20versie%2030.zip", "buurten.zip")
unzip("buurten.zip")

# read shape (Haarlem)
shape <- readOGR("uitvoer_shape",layer=ogrListLayers("uitvoer_shape")[1])[4546:4585,]
# change projection
shape <- spTransform(shape, CRS("+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 
                                +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.999908 
                                +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel 
                                +units=m +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,
                                465.658,-0.406857330322398,0.350732676542563,
                                -1.8703473836068,4.0812 +no_defs"))
# read data
data <- as.tibble(read.table("veiligheid_misdrijven_haarlem.csv", 
                         header=TRUE, sep=";", dec=",",
                         skip = 4, nrows = 40, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
# clean data
data <- data %>%
   separate(X, into = c("buurt", "nummer", "name"), sep = c(6,10)) %>%
   select(-buurt, -nummer) %>%
   arrange(name)

# bind data to shape
shape@data <- cbind(arrange(shape@data,BU_NAAM), data)

# plot interactive map
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(shape) +
  tm_borders(alpha=0.5) +
  tm_fill(c("X2000","X2013"), style="quantile", alpha=.5, 
          palette=colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(5), 
          popup.vars = c("name","X2000","X2013") ) + 
tm_scale_bar()
```

Comment: I doubt whether this is already possible with `tmap`. Maybe you can [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues) detailing what you like to have.

Comment: With regard to binding the data to the shapedata: you are doing it wrong. With `cbind` the neighbourhoods are not matched (unless they are in the exact same order, which isn't the case here). It is better to use `shape <- append_data(shape, data, key.shp = "BU_NAAM", key.data = "name")` (you need to load the `tmaptools`-package for that too).

Comment: @jaap you're right! I had an elaborate version of you're short line in my local version. In an effort to shorten it I made a mistake. Thanks for the line though. It's much shorter, appreciate it. I edited the original question with your correction.

Comment: @jaap I forgot, the names do not match exactly in the two dfs. So I edited the code again with an arrange on the shapefile.